# getImageResource() Android. Is this possible?

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have set an image for an `ImageView` using the `setImageResource(R.drawable.icon1)`.

Now my requirement is to find out what is the image that is set for an `ImageView` and do some processing.

Like

```
if (imageView.getImageResource() == R.drawable.icon1) {
  //do some processing
else if (imageView.getImageResource() == R.drawable.icon2) {
  //do somethign else
else 
 //display
```

So I would like to know if there exists a method(AFAIK, it doesn't) and if it doesn't how to keep a track of what resources have been set for an `ImageView`.

Thanks.
Sana.

Comment: Why not just do it yourself, if you're the one doing the setting?

Comment: I don't understnad what you want to convey. Can you explain.

Comment: I'm suggesting just storing the ID of the image you set into the imageView in some other location when you set it, as Joe suggested.

Comment: The think is I am setting ids of 'n' number images. So I don't know how many ids I have to keep track of, so I just wanted if Android could give me the ids of View that is clicked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're assuming that because you put an integer in, you are able to get an integer back out, and that's not how `setImageResource()` works.  See [ImageView#setImageResource()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource(int)).  This is just a convenience method for you:  what Android is doing behind the scenes, is looking up the Drawable resource (in most cases, it's a BitmapDrawable, but it could be any type), and then applying that resource to the ImageView as a Bitmap object (i.e., image data only -- it does not have any idea what its original "resource id" was previously).

Your best solution is going to be keeping track of the last resource id you used:

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
this.mLastResourceId = R.drawable.image1;
// ...

// Later, when checking the resource:
if (this.mLastResourceId == R.drawable.image1) {
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You should be able to use the tag property as follows:

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon1);
imageView.setTag(Integer.valueOf(R.drawable.icon1));

// later

int drawable = (Integer) imageView.getTag();

switch(drawable) {

    case R.drawable.icon1:
         // do_something....
         break;

    case R.drawable.icon2:
         // do_something....
         break;

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative, if possible, would be to subclass the ImageView and store the integer in an overridden setImageResource().

```
public class MyImageView extends ImageView  {
  int rememberId = -1;
  @override void setImageResource(int resId){
    rememberId = resId;
  }  
  int getMyResId(){
    return rememberId;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to use Bundle and set whatever properties you need.

```
Intent i = new Intent();      
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
      i.putExtra("prop", "value");
```

Comment: Huh? You must be thinking of the `imageView.setTag(Object)` method instead.

Answer (score -1):

```
package com.widget;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

/**
 * custom star type imagebutton that can be obtain the background image resource
 * id.
 * 
 * </p> your layout xml resource might be like the following code: <br>
 * <view class="com.widget.StarButton" <br>
 *      android:id="@+id/starButton" <br>
 *      android:layout_width="wrap_content" <br>
 *      android:layout_height="wrap_content" <br>
 *      android:background="@android:color/background_light" <br>
 *      android:paddingTop="10dp" <br>
 *      android:src="@drawable/star" /> <br>
 * 
 * @author Jeffen
 * 
 */
public class StarButton extends ImageButton {
private int mLastResourceId = -1;

public StarButton(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public StarButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, android.R.attr.imageButtonStyle);
}

public StarButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    setFocusable(true);
}

/**
 * set image resource and sync image resource id.
 */
@Override
public void setImageResource(int resId) {
    super.setImageResource(resId);

    setImageResourceId(resId);
}

public int getImageResourceId() {
    return mLastResourceId;
}

public void setImageResourceId(int resId) {
    mLastResourceId = resId;
}

}
```

Comment: This answer is correct - but also wrong on soo many levels