# switching my imageView between two sources

Tags: android

When I click a button it changes my ImageView from pic1 to pic2, I use this...

```
    ImageView myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImageView );
    myImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic2);
```

and it changes my ImageView to pic2 now I want to be able to click the button again and change it back to pic 1 using...

```
    myImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic1);
```

but I need some way to make a getImageResource so I can run an if statement on which pic is showing and display the other when the button is clicked. For Example if pic 2 is showing it will check which pic is showing and returns pic2 so it knows when the button is clicked to switch it to pic1

Comment: more simple way that is use bool toggle variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getImageResource() Android. Is this possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352132/getimageresource-android-is-this-possible)

Comment: @reinhard.lee im gonna try that

Comment: @cjaxx see my answer.

Comment: If you don't use tag at all, You can use it instead, with xml and setTag or getTag to check value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a flag to identify which image is set.

By default pic1 is selected, add the flag

```
boolean flag = true;
```

Then on imageview click listener check for the flag, if the flag is set then set the imageview with pic2 else pic2.

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if(flag) {
                        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic2);
                    } else {
                        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic1);
                    }
                    flag = !flag;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code and see if it works for you:

Write this before onCreate: `private boolean imageIs = false;`

Write this in onCreate:

```
btnImageChange.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (!imageIs) {
                    imageV.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                    imageIs = true;
                } else {
                    imageV.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round);
                    imageIs = false;
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Yes u r right, we have given the correct answer and even I have got downvote.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a variable, which will have a value when you click the button like

`int x= R.drawable.pic2;`

And when you click the button for changing the image to pic2 your code will be like

```
 ImageView myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImageView );
 myImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic2);
  x=R.drawable.pic2;
```

And if you want to add pic1 again by clicking the button you can use if loop like

```
 ImageView myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImageView );
 if(x=R.drawable.pic2){
  myImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic1);
 }
 else if(x=R.drawable.pic1){

 myImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic2);
 x=R.drawable.pic2;
 }
else{
 myImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic1);
 }
```

Comment: int x again? really?

Comment: @reinhard.lee by mistake sorry